# how to access caption from Semantic Search using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, search, azure-web-app-service, semantic-ui

I'm trying to build a web app that can perform a semantic search using natural language and return the answer as a result.  Using response.data.results, I am able to see the caption text in the console under semanticSearch->captions->text.

[console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJMnR.png)

However I can't figure out what is the syntax to access that info.  I tried response.data.results.semanticSearch.captions[0].text but that is giving me an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'captions')"

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!
Kenneth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming that JSON on your screenshot coming from the log `response.data.results`, it turns out it that's an array. You just need to specify the indice like;

```
const result = response.data.results[0]; // or 1? whichever you need;
console.log(semanticSearch.captions[0].text)
```

[image: log screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use stringify to turn the object to a string, then parsed it accordingly.

```
    var output = JSON.stringify(response.data.results);                      
    var pos = output.indexOf("text"); 
    var partOutput = output.slice(pos+7,pos+2000);
    var pos2 = partOutput.indexOf("\"highlights\"");             
    var finalOutput = partOutput.slice(0,pos2-2);              
    console.log(finalOutput);
```